# when we call a power automate flow from power apps, what permission the user need to have on the power automate flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

when we call a power automate flow from power apps, do we need to grant the users specific permission on the flow? i mean do we need to share the flow with the users who will be calling the flow from the power apps? or sharing the power apps with the users will be sufficient?
we are calling the flow using this formula from our canvas app:-

```
PurchaseRequestApprovalSubmission.Run(Text(HelpDeskWorkflow))
```